# Pandas read_csv datetime error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file (aal_21_02_2018) with the following format:

```
,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2018-02-21 08:01:00,1744.2,1746.0,1738.6,1738.6,34727
2018-02-21 08:02:00,1738.8,1743.0,1738.8,1740.0,6483
2018-02-21 08:03:00,1739.6,1739.6,1737.8,1738.2,6622
```

I want to turn this file into a DataFrame. When I run the following method:

```
df = read_csv('aal_21_02_2018', index_col='datetime')
```

The following error is shown:

```
ValueError: Index datetime invalid
```

How do I corretly parse this CSV file into a DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unnamed column so pass the ordinal position

```
df = read_csv('aal_21_02_2018', index_col=0)
```

Example:

```
In[4]:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=0)
df

Out[4]: 
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
2018-02-21 08:01:00  1744.2  1746.0  1738.6  1738.6   34727
2018-02-21 08:02:00  1738.8  1743.0  1738.8  1740.0    6483
2018-02-21 08:03:00  1739.6  1739.6  1737.8  1738.2    6622
```

If you require a datetimeIndex then you can pass `parse_dates=[0]`:

```
In[7]:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
df

Out[7]: 
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
2018-02-21 08:01:00  1744.2  1746.0  1738.6  1738.6   34727
2018-02-21 08:02:00  1738.8  1743.0  1738.8  1740.0    6483
2018-02-21 08:03:00  1739.6  1739.6  1737.8  1738.2    6622
```

We can see the index is now a datetimeIndex:

```
In[8]:
df.index

Out[8]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-21 08:01:00', '2018-02-21 08:02:00',
               '2018-02-21 08:03:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Regarding how this happened, the default `to_csv` behaviour is to output the index as an unnamed column, if you pass `index_label='datetime'` then this will write out a named index:

```
In[10]:
df.to_csv(index_label='datetime')

Out[10]: 'datetime,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2018-02-21 08:01:00,1744.2,1746.0,1738.6,1738.6,34727
2018-02-21 08:02:00,1738.8,1743.0,1738.8,1740.0,6483
2018-02-21 08:03:00,1739.6,1739.6,1737.8,1738.2,6622'
```

Then your original code would've worked:

```
In[12]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df.to_csv(index_label='datetime')), index_col='datetime')

Out[12]: 
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
datetime                                                   
2018-02-21 08:01:00  1744.2  1746.0  1738.6  1738.6   34727
2018-02-21 08:02:00  1738.8  1743.0  1738.8  1740.0    6483
2018-02-21 08:03:00  1739.6  1739.6  1737.8  1738.2    6622
```

Comment: correct, no name given for column, datetime is type not name

Comment: Thank you! I believe the person who created the file used the pandas.to_csv method without any arguments.

Comment: @Warmley the default behaviour is to output the index column as unnamed, if you pass `index_label='datetime'` then it will produce a csv with a named column, I will update